# Difficulty implementing delegate methods in an objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have a table view which I am using as a form.
The first cell has an editable text field. The second cell, when clicked, loads a semi modal date picker. I used this: http://reednj.tumblr.com/post/1346445326/ios-semi-modal-date-picker-for-iphone

Anyway, I've defined my datepicker and set its delegate inside the tableviewcontroller like so:

```
TDDatePickerController* datePickerView = [[TDDatePickerController alloc] 
                                              initWithNibName:@"TDDatePickerController" 
                                              bundle:nil];
    [datePickerView setDelegate:self];
    [self presentSemiModalViewController:datePickerView];
```

Now the methods to handle the button clicks are defined as

```
-(void)datePickerSetDate:(TDDatePickerController*)viewController;
-(void)datePickerClearDate:(TDDatePickerController*)viewController;
-(void)datePickerCancel:(TDDatePickerController*)viewController;
```

So when the cancel button is pressed I would like the semi-modal date picker to be dismissed, So I've got:

```
-(void)datePickerCancel:(TDDatePickerController*)viewController{
[self dismissSemiModalViewController:viewController];
}
```

But this makes the app crash with the error

```
-[__NSCFType cancelDateEdit:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe738c00
```

2012-09-18 10:23:47.254 JRPBaseCamp[7612:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType cancelDateEdit:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe738c00'

So I looked up the cancelDateEdit method  in TDDatePickerController:

```
-(IBAction)cancelDateEdit:(id)sender {
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datePickerCancel:)]) {
    [self.delegate datePickerCancel:self];
} 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It must be something obvious that I'm overlooking. Any help is much appreciated, I'm fairly new to iOS and the whole concept of delegates is really confusing me.
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it's being released from memory too soon. Have you tried adding a breakpoint?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where might it be getting released? I'm using ARC.

Comment: Check out this answer to set up breakpoints to understand where it's breaking. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5236957/879119

Comment: Try making datePickerView an ivar or property and see if that helps. It's not clear from your post where you create datePickerView, but it's probably being deallocated after whatever method it's in finishes.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks.. I was creating datePickerView in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I made it a property instead and allocated it in viewDidLoad. It seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The unrecognized selector sent means nothing is responding to cancelDateEdit: selector. You can use the debugger to search what kind of object is 0xe738c00 and then look for the appropriate selector there.